# Excel VBA - Have VBA script loop through rows

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have a VBA script that copies data from one sheet to another. The data copied is put into a formula and the calculated amount is copied back over to the original sheet. I am trying to get it so that the VBA script does this for each row. I have 1000 rows of data.

```
Sub Rating()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("SoapUI - Single")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("STpremcalc")

        ws2.Range("B3").Value = ws1.Range("B3").Value

        ws2.Range("B4").Value = ws1.Range("C3").Value

        ws2.Range("B5").Value = ws1.Range("D3").Value

        ws2.Range("B6").Value = ws1.Range("E3").Value

        ws2.Range("E3").Value = ws1.Range("F3").Value

        ws2.Range("E4").Value = ws1.Range("G3").Value

        ws2.Range("E5").Value = ws1.Range("H3").Value

        ws2.Range("E6").Value = ws1.Range("I3").Value

        ws2.Range("G3").Value = ws1.Range("J3").Value

        ws2.Range("G4").Value = ws1.Range("K3").Value

        ws2.Range("G5").Value = ws1.Range("L3").Value

        ws2.Range("J3").Value = ws1.Range("N3").Value

        ws2.Range("J4").Value = ws1.Range("O3").Value

        ws2.Range("J6").Value = ws1.Range("P3").Value

        ws2.Range("B9").Value = ws1.Range("Q3").Value

        ws2.Range("C9").Value = ws1.Range("R3").Value

        ws2.Range("D9").Value = ws1.Range("S3").Value

        ws2.Range("E9").Value = ws1.Range("T3").Value

        ws2.Range("B10").Value = ws1.Range("U3").Value

        ws2.Range("C10").Value = ws1.Range("V3").Value

        ws2.Range("D10").Value = ws1.Range("W3").Value

        ws2.Range("E10").Value = ws1.Range("X3").Value

        ws2.Range("B11").Value = ws1.Range("Y3").Value

        ws2.Range("C11").Value = ws1.Range("Z3").Value

        ws2.Range("D11").Value = ws1.Range("AA3").Value

        ws2.Range("E11").Value = ws1.Range("AB3").Value

        ws1.Range("AW3").Value = ws2.Range("M4").Value

        ws1.Range("AX3").Value = ws2.Range("M5").Value

        ws1.Range("AY3").Value = ws2.Range("M6").Value

End Sub
```

Also I understand that this may be a very inefficient way to perform this task but I dont know how to better it. So if you have a way to make this more efficient, it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Update code as per @user3598756 advice

Comment: The problem is that the range you are pasting to doesn't seem to have any pattern in terms of where to move to next, so a loop would require a **lot** of `if/else` type syntax which would probably be equally as inefficient.

Comment: The only thing that would change is the row number of the copied data. for example should be something like: `Sheets("SoapUI - Single").Range("B" & i).Copy`
    `Sheets("STpremcalc").Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a fan of copy/ paste procedure, but if you must use it then the following statements

```
Sheets("SoapUI - Single").Range("B3").Copy
Sheets("STpremcalc").Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

Sheets("SoapUI - Single").Range("C3").Copy
Sheets("STpremcalc").Range("B4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

Sheets("SoapUI - Single").Range("D3").Copy
Sheets("STpremcalc").Range("B5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

Sheets("SoapUI - Single").Range("E3").Copy
Sheets("STpremcalc").Range("B6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
```

can be simplified into

```
Sheets("SoapUI - Single").Range("B3:E3").Copy
Sheets("STpremcalc").Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True
```

Other than above, you can simplify

```
    Sheets("SoapUI - Single").Range("Q3").Copy
    Sheets("STpremcalc").Range("B9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

    Sheets("SoapUI - Single").Range("R3").Copy
    Sheets("STpremcalc").Range("C9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

    Sheets("SoapUI - Single").Range("S3").Copy
    Sheets("STpremcalc").Range("D9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

    Sheets("SoapUI - Single").Range("T3").Copy
    Sheets("STpremcalc").Range("E9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
```

into

```
    Sheets("SoapUI - Single").Range("Q3:T3").Copy
    Sheets("STpremcalc").Range("B9:E9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
```

I think you can do the rest by yourself.

---

**EDIT:** Since the OP edits his question. The following can be simplified

```
    ws2.Range("B3").Value = ws1.Range("B3").Value

    ws2.Range("B4").Value = ws1.Range("C3").Value

    ws2.Range("B5").Value = ws1.Range("D3").Value

    ws2.Range("B6").Value = ws1.Range("E3").Value

    ws2.Range("E3").Value = ws1.Range("F3").Value

    ws2.Range("E4").Value = ws1.Range("G3").Value

    ws2.Range("E5").Value = ws1.Range("H3").Value

    ws2.Range("E6").Value = ws1.Range("I3").Value
```

by using the **loop** procedure like this

```
For i = 1 To 4
    ws2.Cells(i + 2, 2) = ws1.Cells(3, i + 1)    'Or you can use `ws1.Cells(3, i + 1).Value2` if you only need the value without its format like date or currency
    ws2.Cells(i + 2, 5) = ws1.Cells(3, i + 5)
Next i
```

The rest is yours.

Comment: @RossWatson See my edit. I believe you can do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

not much to do but that little can be:

- use variables to reference worksheets and improve both code readability and efficiency

  ```
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet    
  Set ws1 = Worksheets("SoapUI - Single")
  Set ws2 = Worksheets("STpremcalc")
  ```
- use `Range1.Value = Range2.Value` pattern to copy/paste values between ranges it'

  ```
  ws2.Range("B3").Value = ws1.Range("B3").Value
  ws2.Range("B4").Value = ws1.Range("C4").Value
  ...
  ```

Comment: @Ross: it'd be nice of you to give proper feedbacks to people trying helping you